# Github integration & Services (How to enable)

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-sns

I have github repository with Amazon SNS service enable. It suppose to push message, but it never does it with grey dot "this hook has never been triggered". 
I can trigger this service manually by clicking "Test service". It works fine.

I've tried git push (pushing changes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are adding ARN into Github field, make sure you use relevant AWS role and it has sufficient permissions to access your lambda code.